# How to speed up running speed of the mvn archetype:generate?

Tags: maven

I was trying to run the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -D"groupId=com.example" -DartifactId="my-app" `
  -D"archetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" `
  -DarchetypeVersion="1.4" `
  -D"interactiveMode=false" -X
```

In this simple command, it took around 2 minute to complete. The hotspot of the total time is here:

```
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
```

The `archetype-catalog.xml` has `12.3M` in file size and the network speed of the `repo.maven.apache.org` site is slow. So that the total run time become very long.

Does Apache Maven have any cache mechanism for this can increase the run speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your connectivity issues (in my env your initial command takes about 10 seconds), however you may avoid consulting global catalog by specifying `-DarchetypeCatalog=internal`, smth. like:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=my-app \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 \
  -DarchetypeCatalog=internal \
  -DinteractiveMode=false -X
```

Comment: The doc said "The Archetype Plugin comes bundled with an internal catalog. This one is used by default." from https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html

Comment: I don't know why my mvn use global catalog by default. Do you know how to check this out?

Comment: @WillHuang I just know that global catalog is unreliable :) for example, I can't even open https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml in browser

Comment: I actually install maven by using `choco install maven`.

Comment: @WillHuang that does not make sense how you have installed maven, technically archetype is kind of general artifact and so it is enough to know GAV (group, artifcat, version) coordinates to be able to work with it, all other issues are related to `archetype` plugin

Comment: Agreed. I still can't find out where is the default value. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/88981/188544024-ea0a886d-c589-42a0-a4a9-3c64a217abff.png